# What is really happen (actual process) when we hash a particular string or word

Tags: java, hashtable, hash, bloom-filter

Hi am trying to develop a counting bloom filter in java. i really searched most of the sources about the bloom filter.. The thing i understood is when we hash (do hashing) the particular string or word, the result of hashing will return one value so that we can store the content in that resultant value place.
But my big question is how to do the hashing (the algorithm). What really happens when we hash a particular string or word. Can u please explain me what really happens when we hash a particular string or word (Like how the particular final value arrives when we do hashing on particular string or word). I also read there is also chances for collision. Can you also address, Why the resultant hash value is not unique (Why its sometimes returns same hash value for different inputs). And do i really need to write the code to do hashing or is there any inbuilt functions in java to do hashing.

Comment: Please study the subject a little bit before asking questions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: In a bloom filer you need more than one hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get a hash code by calling `hashCode()` on any object. In particular for class `String` from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29):

> public int hashCode()
>
> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object
>   is computed as
>
> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[ 1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
>
> using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n
>   is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash
>   value of the empty string is zero.)

Answer (score 1):

"Hashing" is a function

`H: I -> O`

Where usually the set `I` is much bigger or more complex than `O`. In hash table `I` is the class of your elements is, and `O` is the set of positive integers. Particularly, in a bloom filter you have `n` different functions. To develop a hash function you need to extract different characteristics of similar objects. For example, for character strings you can have :

- the length
- the first character
- the number of occurrences of a specific character
- the string evaluated  as a polynomial `h(S) = sum (s(i)*31^i) mod d`

When using multiple hash collision of characteristics should be avoided, for example using `number of voyels` and `number of non-voyels` is not really helpful. There are some characteristics to a hash function must have, look at the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

Answer (score 0):

The code executed for `String` is this one:

```
public int hashCode() {
int h = hash;
    int len = count;
if (h == 0 && len > 0) {
    int off = offset;
    char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Hash is a function (not a bijection) and therefore, different inputs can produce the same result. This is the basics of hash functions

Answer (score 0):

Java allows you to override the hashCode() method for your Classes to use a hashing algorithm

```
public class Employee {


   // Default implementation might want to use "name" for as part of hashCode
   private String name; 

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
     // We know that ID is always unique, so don't use name in calculating 
     // the hash code. & hashCode() is an int
     return id;
   }
}
```

*(if you are going to override hashCode you should also override equals.)

The hashcode is computed per object stored in the collection. 
It is computed using a standard algorithm.
You can indeed override the hashcode method on a per object basis.
one  way to implement a hashcode method is using HashcodeBuilder.

Hope this helps. Search more in stack overflow related to this article ,you can get more descriptive answers.